# java versus c# - which one is safer in terms of security?

Tags: c#, java, security, reverse-engineering

I and some buddies have an argument here -

in which langauge is it safer by terms of writing a code that cannot be hacked?

by hacked I mean that after the code is encrypted, or turned into executable ,  it can be reversed enginered into some kind of intermidate code (like java byte code) , or even the real high level program code itself .

This agruments aruse in general because one of us is about to start a big software project,but he's  afraid that his competitors will steal some of his very-efficient algorithams.

It would be nice if any of you could present some pros and cons for each langauge .

thanks.

Comment: i think this question will bring alot of arguments

Comment: If he has innovations that are so vastly superior to anything widely known that it's worth reverse engineering to steal, and he's keeping them a proprietary secret instead of publishing a paper and contributing it to an appropriate project, clearly a MSFT solution is the appropriate platform for him.

Comment: Voting to re-open.  I disagree.  This question is not subjective or argumentatitve.  It has a very clear and simple answer.  Neither.  No code is secure from discovery.

Comment: Putting your code on a server controlled by only yourself is the safest. Then offer your efficient algorithms as a service of some kind.

Comment: Arjan- thats a nice solution. let me get this striaght , you are talking about SaaS right? (cloud computing)

Comment: @Mystere Man - in that case, the question is a duplicate of the many SO questions of the form "how best can I prevent reverse engineering".

Comment: @Stephen C - unlike so many others on SO, I don't see a problem with duplicate posts.  Often, each time a subject is revisted new information is presented, or new insights into the subject.  Closing questions based on duplication is short sighted in my opinion.

Comment: @Mystere Man - fine.  Get on 'meta' and convince the admins.  In the mean time, you know what is going to happen to duplicate questions.

Comment: @Stephen C - I'm not sure what Meta has to do with anything.  Closing questions is a community thing.  You and I are both members of the community.  You can vote to close, I can vote to re-open.  If enough people believe one way or another, the admins don't have much say in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't really get to work with Java so I'm more familiar with C#.
In C# (or other .net languages) you can use easy and free tools like Reflector to see ALL of the code written inside an executable or dll.

You can always try obfuscating the code with the most advanced tools, so this won't be revealed easily, but I'm pretty sure that if the code is worth enough for someone to hack/reverse-engineer, It WILL be, and it's just a matter of time till that happens!

Even with lower level languages like C/C++, if the code is worth it, the people interested will find out how it works.

Bottom line : EVERYTHING IS HACKABLE/REVERSE-ENGINEERABLE!

:)

Comment: just reverse engineer the program :) , no need to hack the code

Comment: cant we just put the hacker on infinite loop if he tries to hack it? :P

Comment: So if we cant find salvation in any of these langauages , maybe we should try some hardware deffense? like the one that smart cards like SIM has ? ( which is actully revese engineerable :/) . Is there any way to raise the time to get it hacked to high enough , lets say a year or two ?

Comment: @RanZilber - No.  And frankly, you are probably *WAY* over valuing how precious your source code is.  It's not rocket science.

Comment: @Mystere Man - first i'd like to thank you for all answers in this discussion. Yes, itsnot rocket science , and I probably overestimed my code .  But i stil cant understand, how come it still takes months to reverse engineer virus-like programs.

Comment: @RanZilber - Viruses are low-level code that take advantage of low-level holes in operating systems.  If you want to write you code in hand optimized assembler, it will be hard to reverse engineer as well, but it will take you 100x longer to write it

Comment: Virus like programs work totally different, and is a different subject altogether! They use techniques like Code that can change itself, rootkits that are hard to reveal and shellcode which is really hard to write an algorithm in. You won't be doing this since this isn't realistic to write something useful using these techniques, but only something small that can vandalize and cause damage.

Comment: @Mystere Man - thanks for all the answers . We decided to drop this project , and move one to a bigger project - one that will allow code protection! good night

Comment: I would first concentrate on writing good, efficient code that works and get the job you need done. Only then, think about how much it's worth to you, and use that money to hire companies that specialize in security and intellectual property rights. :)

Comment: You don't always have to expose your code, meaning you don't necesserily have to sell your binaries. You could always sell the product as a service and have the algorithm run in the cloud. This way the code stays on your servers. (as long as you protect them good enough! :P )

Answer (score 1):

Both Java and C# can be decompiled to (mostly) your original source code.  In .Net you have Reflector, in Java you have DJ's Decompiler.  It works both ways.

In the end, it doesn't really matter.  If someone is determined, they can always dis-assemble your code and still get the "efficient algorithms".  Any code readable by the CPU is readable by a human.

Comment: So how does companies like microsoft that sell many cots protect thierself? they do that by buidling in thier own "secret" langauge ?

Comment: @RanZiber - No.  They don't protect themselves.  The fact is, if someone steals your code and tries to use it in their apps, you can just as easily see that and sue them.  Microsoft doesn't protect any of their programs written in .NET (of which there are quite a few).  There is simply no real point to it.

Comment: Goes for their programs not written in .net too! Even though they spend a lot of money and research into Security issues, it's still very easy to download hacked versions of Windows, Office, VS, you name it...

Comment: "you can just as easily see that and sue them" - can you elaborate how they can easily see that ? do they leave "tracks" on thier code?

Comment: @RanZilber - My point is that if someone reverse engineers your code and uses it in their competing app.  You can reverse engineer their code and prove in court that they stole it.

Answer (score 0):

Since by "security" you seem to mean protection against reverse-engineering, your best bet is probably native code like C/C++... most interpreted languages are **much** easier to decompile than native code, although you can obfuscate them to make it harder.

Comment: I'd like to hear more about it . In which ways can I obfuscate on those hackers?

Comment: @RanZilber - Ther are obfuscators for both Java and C#.  dotfuscator comes with Visual Studio, for instance.

Comment: Good obfuscators aren't free, but mediocre ones are rather easy to make by yourself actually! I made my own obfuscator for .NET once that just went through every piece of code using the Mono library, then renamed every method and class and variable to something random. That all worked -- except that reflection no longer worked. But if your code doesn't use reflection, then it's not too hard to build one yourself.

Comment: But in Reflector you could still probably see the random function names and variables and their code, right ? I wonder how you can make the code unviewable to Reflector...?

Comment: Yeah, you can always see what's there -- the only trick is in making the information useless, since you can't really hide something that's already on the user's disk.